# Managing checkouts of same binary file in different branches in Perforce

Tags: branch, perforce, unreal-engine4, perforce-integrate

How to prevent checking out / changing one binary file in different branches of the same content. Situations like: designers have edited some game level (*.umap binary file) in their branch. Programmes changed same file in their branch (for example - added some blueprint on this game level). So now we have three different versions of this file, one in master branch before all changes, one in designers branch without programmes changes, one in programmes branch without designers changes. And now we must merge designers changes and programmes changes into master branch, but we cant.

So the question is - how to organise right this situations? Maybe we can setup perforce to checkout binary file in multiply branches at the same time, or something like this? Thanks...

Comment: UE4, eh? What's the rationale behind your programmer and designer branches?

Also, there is some limited ability to diff/merge some of the binary files, but not sure how friendly it would be across branches.

Comment: Maybe you should have everyone make changes to binary files only on the master branch and not bother including them on the programmer and designer branches?

Comment: Instead of branches, consider using sub-levels split by responsibility domain, e.g. a sublevel for AI for the devs and a sublevel for environment for the designers.

Comment: Designers commits must pass through our technical artist before been accepted and merged to main branch. Only technical artist can merge designers commits, that is why we use different branches for programmers and designers. This problem comes almost exactly only with level files *.umap, witch can be checked out in the same time in different branches, making changes in them - unmergeble. I found the exact my case in this maillist - [link](http://maillist.perforce.com/pipermail/perforce-user/2007-January/056465.html), but there is no solution exept pre-triggers and scripting commits operations.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of different ways to think about this.

If you don't want work to continue/begin in one branch, until changes from another branch have been merged in to it, you can use Helix (Perforce) Protections, to give users read-only access to the branch.

This means they will be able to open files for edit, but won't be able to submit their changes.

More info about protections is here:
  https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4sag/chapter.security.html

The protections would need to be changed, when you are ready for work on the other branches to start.

If you want a file to be automatically checked out on all branches, each time someone checks it out on any branch where it exists, you would currently have to script this.

You could do it using the broker and a workspace for every branch, that has a view that just includes the files you want to be checked out everywhere.

The files would then need to be checked out in these workspaces and locked, so that other users can't submit to these branches until the locks are removed.

This is not trivial and may have a performance impact.

You might also be able to do it using pre-command triggers, if your server version is new enough.

If you want to go in to more detail about any of the above, I recommend you contact Perforce Technical Support.

Hope this helps,
Jen.

Comment: Well, readonly rights is not an option, designers must have rights to edit obviously. Scripting checkout operations if what i was afraid for... So i am making a conclusion that there is no way to prevent situations like i described? And branches are only suitable for managing text files and not binary?

Comment: Branches are fine for managing binary files. Your problem lies with the unusual approval model you have for this situation combined with the unmergeability of binary files.